# Why Widget does not update when it's added

Tags: android, service, widget

I've created a widget which is updated by a service. However, its interface processed by that service is not updated when it's added, but the second run of the app.

widgetProvider.java:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MetalPriceService.class);
        intent.setAction(MetalPriceService.UPDATEPRICE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_refresh_btn, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        context.startService(intent);
}
```

widgetPriceUpdateService.java:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    try {
        updatePrice(intent); //deal with interface updating stuffs
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    stopSelf(startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make yourself a RemoteViews and update the widget(s) directly in the Service. You'll get your AppWidgetManager via:

AppWidgetManager mgr=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

Everything else is as normal.

If you really want to force the existing AppWidgetProvider to do the work, send a broadcast with a custom action to your component, and call onUpdate() yourself from onReceive() when you get

Comment: this is what I have done, it can be updated but not the first run. Could you please explain more specifically, since I have saw this "omnipotent" answer a lot of times on other sites.